# mysql - Recovering databases from ibdata1 , .frm and .idb

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a server running a mysql instance which crashed today. Now there are a massive amounts of tables in multiple database exceeding over 200GB stored on disk. After the server crash mysql is refusing to restart again with the following errors :

```
2014-09-15 17:33:58 10339 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-09-15 17:33:58 10339 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-09-15 17:33:58 10339 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-09-15 18:02:31 10339 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2014-09-15 18:02:31 10339 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 7 log sequence number 220915324226
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 2 log sequence number 220717629622
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 4 log sequence number 204234247539
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 11 log sequence number 220909375043
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 5 log sequence number 220915302779
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 6 log sequence number 220913291113
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 1290824 log sequence number 220786399986
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 1277953 log sequence number 218872957756
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 1291526 log sequence number 220741466699
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 45 log sequence number 220755399357
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780 InnoDB: Error: page 1291070 log sequence number 220698577049
InnoDB: is in the future! Current system log sequence number 187979020300.
InnoDB: Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
InnoDB: tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. See
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: for more information.
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 841892569 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139953797425024 in file fil0fil.cc line 5591
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:02:32 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=134217728
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=5000
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 819301283 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x35)[0x9139b5]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x3e8)[0x6751c8]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3633e0f750]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39)[0x3633a35c39]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x3633a37348]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xb0cd43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xadac2b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xadb29b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xac8fca]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa940bd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa8895e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa88c5e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa8af5b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0xa76a25]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x9bbfc6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z24ha_initialize_handlertonP13st_plugin_int+0x46)[0x58dda6]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x703b20]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11plugin_initPiPPci+0x88d)[0x7070dd]
/usr/sbin/mysqld[0x5846cf]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_Z11mysqld_mainiPPc+0x3ac)[0x5855ec]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x3633a21d65]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(__gxx_personality_v0+0x2f1)[0x579839]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
140915 18:02:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /database/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid ended
```

I did the following step none of which helped
 a ) Set innodb_force_recovery = 1 to 6
 b ) Delete the ib_logfile and let mysql recreate them

Now i also don't have any recent backup of the tables, and the data just cannot be lost. So is there any way to restore the database using ibdata1 , .frm and .idb files. Please let me know if there is a solution to this.

Comment: https://twindb.com/recover-corrupt-mysql-database/

Comment: `read_buffer_size` of 128MB and 5000 connections does not look like a good combination by the way.

Answer (score -1):

Your InnoDB tables are definitely have errors, but it seems to be that the reason why mysql can't start is lack of memory.
It's from your error log:

```
key_buffer_size=33554432
read_buffer_size=134217728
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=5000
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 819301283 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.
```

Please make sure your server have enough RAM (should have at least 820G of RAM). If not - decrease some parameters in my.cnf
There are many memory allocating parameter including some for InnoDB engine. Please consider them also.
If it is the problem then again start recovering from innodb_force_recovery = 1 to 6

Comment: nope. This is assertion failure: "InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 841892569 in space 0,
InnoDB: space name ./ibdata1,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 16384, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
2014-09-15 18:02:32 7f4988616780  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 139953797425024 in file fil0fil.cc line 5591"

Comment: The server has 16GB of RAM and mysql was running perfectly fine for the last 10 months